# I have a .bashrc file in the root of my server and inside of it has some functions

Tags: bashrc

for instance

function mysqldumpSafe {adds user and password and dumps}

in ubuntu command line.. how do i run this "mysqldumpSafe" to execute the function?

super noob question...

my .bashrc file

```
function cleanStatic {

    rm -rf ~/public_html/pub/static/frontend ~/public_html/pub/static/adminhtml ~/public_html/pub/static/_cache ~/public_html/pub/static/deployed_version.txt;

    rm -rf ~/public_html/var/view_preprocessed;

    php ~/public_html/bin/magento cache:flush full_page;

}



function cleanAll {

    rm -rf ~/public_html/pub/static/frontend ~/public_html/pub/static/adminhtml ~/public_html/pub/static/_cache ~/public_html/pub/static/deployed_version.txt;

    rm -rf ~/public_html/var/view_preprocessed;

    php ~/public_html/bin/magento cache:flush;

    redis-cli -h redis flushall;

    curl -X 'PURGE' -H'X-Magento-Tags-Pattern: .*' varnish;

}



function deployAll {

    php ~/public_html/bin/magento setup:di:compile;

    php ~/public_html/bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -s standard;

    }



function deploySafe {

    php ~/public_html/bin/magento maintenance:enable;

    cleanAll;

    deployAll;

    php ~/public_html/bin/magento maintenance:disable;

}
```

The bash file sits one directory above public_html but when i'm in public html i can run basic bin commands such as : `php bin/magento cache:clean`

but since these custom bash commands have like 3 commands in one.. i wanted to figure out how to use them.

Answer (score 1):

https://linuxize.com/post/bash-functions/ explains `bash` functions in detail.

In general, to run your function, just open a `bash` terminal, enter the name of the function (`mysqldumpSafe` in your case) followed by any arguments (space-separated), and press Enter.

Comment: that's kind of what i was thinking but it doesn't seem to be working. I posted the actual file contents above. @Georgelemental

Answer (score 1):

The .bashrc file is user-specific, so if you do want to use the function you need to switch your shell to root user via

```
sudo -i
```

You will get interactive bash prompt and at that point should be able to use that function

Comment: do i just write php mysqldumpSafe(); in the terminal?

Comment: If this is a `bash` function, you should write just `mysqldumpSafe`.

Comment: @Supplement Bash functions can be invoked directly without parenthesis. Now, why have you mentioned php , though ? Is the function in question actually php code or bash code ? Better yet, can you provide a minimal example so we could understand exactly what you are trying to do ?

Comment: I'll post it above.. @SergiyKolodyazhnyy

Comment: I don't have root access but i think i can use this just like i would use any other bin command, although it doesn't seem to work